# how to sort varchar column containing numeric values with linq lambdas to Entity

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I am using linq lambdas to query the MySql (Note MySql not Sql) with Entity Framwork in MVC. Now i have one table `product` one of column this table is `price` with datatype "VARCHAR" (Accept i can't change type to INT as it can hold values like "N/A",etc).

I want to sort `price` column numerically with linq Lambdas.I have tried bellow.I am using `Model` values to filter query.

```
var query = ent.Product.Where(b => b.cp == Model.CodePostal);

if (Model.order_by_flg == 2)
{
    query = query.OrderByDescending(a => a.price.PadLeft(10, '0'));
}
```

But it will not work and give me bellow error.

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   PadLeft(Int32, Char)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

As it cant convert to Sql statement by Entity Framwork.

I also tried bellow.

```
var query = ent.Product.Where(b => b.cp == Model.CodePostal);

if (Model.order_by_flg == 2)
{
    query = query.OrderByDescending(a => a.price.Length).ThenBy(a => a.price);
}
```

But i can't do this because it works for List but i cant first make list and then do this as i am using linq `Skip()` and `Take()` so first i have to sort it.

So how can i sort price column of type "VARCHAR" in Linq lambda?

**EDIT**

In table it is :

```
59,59,400,185,34
```

Wnen i use OrderBy.ThenBy it gives

```
34,59,59,106,185,400
```

It looks right as sorting ascending But when i use OrderByDescending.ThenBy it gives

```
106,185,400,34,59,59
```

So i can't use this.

**NOTE: Please give reasons before Downvote so i can improve my question...**

Comment: What happens then you try the latter approach with OrderByDescending().ThenBy()?

Comment: Not sorting as expected it sorts values like "106,185,400,34..." even i used OrderByDecending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simulate fixed `PadLeft` in LINQ to Entities with the canonical function [DbFunctions.Right](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220112(v=vs.113).aspx) like this

instead of this

```
a.price.PadLeft(10, '0')
```

use this

```
DbFunctions.Right("000000000" + a.price, 10)
```

I haven't tested it with MySql provider, but canonical functions defined in the `DbFunctions` are supposed to be supported by any provider.

Comment: Thanks it works!!! Can u tell me what exactly DbFunctions.Right("000000000" + a.price, 10) do ?

Comment: Sure. It appends 9 zeroes at the left of the text, and then truncates the result by taking right 10 characters. So for instance "12" -> "00000000012" => "0000000012". while "1234" => "0000000001234" => "0000001234"

Answer (score 2):

> It looks right as sorting ascending But when i use OrderByDescending.ThenBy it gives
>
> 106,185,400,34,59,59

That's because you're ordering by length descending, then value *ascending*.
What you need is simply to sort *both* by descending;

```
query = query.OrderByDescending(a => a.price.Length)
              .ThenByDescending(a => a.price);
```

This *should* be faster than prepending numbers to sort, since you don't need to do multiple calculations per row but can instead sort by existing data.

Comment: Yes you are right i missed .ThenByDescending. It's working i got 2 solution for the same problem!!!